# How to remove only position(top and left) of Style attr using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically setting the position attr of the element only when the view is out of viewport of the window, in other case default value is set from the css file ,

```
.css( { "left": (left + 20) + "px", "top": (top+10) + "px" } );
```

Once the dynamic position is set, I want to remove the position attr alone.

I can remove style attribute it will also my display property of style which is required.

Is there a way to to remove the position attr alone?

Comment: .removeAttr('style:left') this doest work any equlent of this ?

Answer (score 30):

Perhaps, your best Bet would be to simply put them to their default value. Top and left have the default value "auto". So:

```
jQuery(selector).css({
   'top': 'auto',
   'left': 'auto'
})
```

Answer (score 7):

`$(el).css('top', '');` will remove the inline style declaration, reverting back to either what is specified in your stylesheet or the default.

Comment: Great answer that allows default CSS styles to be reverted to, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you're asking for removing a `position` HTML attribute, a `position` style, or `top` and `left` styles. In any case, you can remove any attribute with `$.removeAttr()`, and you can remove (dynamically assigned) styles with `$.css({ styleName: '' })`;

Edit: it seems you want `$.css({ position: '' })`, or more likely `$.css({ position: 'static' })`, as that is the default value.

Comment: i would remove a position style , but if i use  $.removeAttr() it will remove the entire style not the left and top alone